# Is it fine to create a Trait just to specify a contract but not using it from a polymorphism point-of-view?

Tags: scala, class, traits, class-design

So, let's say I have a trait of the following form -

```
trait QueryBuilder {
  def build(filters: Seq[CustomFilter]): CustomDBQuery
}
```

With this, I'm looking to establish an abstraction which says that any query builder should conform to this contract.

Now, let's say I have a `SeriesQueryBuilder` defined like this which has its own implementation of the `build()` method -

```
object SeriesQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {
  override def build(filters: Seq[CustomFilter]): CustomDDBQuery = ???
}
```

Now, my question is - I don't want to pass the `QueryBuilder` in other methods but instead pass only the specific concrete instance of the sub type. In that case, is it wrong to have the `QueryBuilder` trait in the first place just to enforce the contract a "query builder" should follow? To generalise it, let's also say the trait doesn't have any methods common to all of the query builders.

Comment: Yeah that is actually a good idea, you do not know what will happen in the future and you would need a new query builder. Or maybe you may want to mock it on your tests. Since you already have a trait, you are decoupled, thus changes will be easier.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you're right, and that was my idea. But without actually having `QueryBuilder` in my methods, I feel that I'm not enforcing the query builders to extend this trait, right? I mean, another dev could just "get away" but not extending this trait at all.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't understand that part. Yeah, you should use **QueryBuilder** everywhere, the only place where you should use **SeriesQueryBuilder** is on the main _(or something closer)_ which begins the dependency chain.